# Ruby on Rails Params set recipient and sender with users_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, parameters, psql

Have a recipient and sender, both of the same class(Message) for a messaging system in rails. Want to set the params for both i.e. if user creates a message sender by default is the user_id and recipient will be the contact selected from the users contact list.

Currently the database is only receiving a user_id to the recipient_id column which is wrong and should be to sender_id column. Sender_id receives nothing.

After reading, some say not to amend the params as this is bad practice. So set a hidden field in the message view (like the body and title) yet this isn't pushing in to the database.

Two questions, is this process an appropriate rails practice? (ask this as new to rails) If not: can you advise another path or direction? If so: any ideas/thoughts why this isn't saving in to the database?

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "sender_id"

  has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates_presence_of :firstname, allow_blank: false
  validates_presence_of :surname, allow_blank: false

end
```

message model

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sender_id"
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "recipient_id"

    validates_presence_of :body, :title
end
```

Messages controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :message, only: [:show]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @messages = current_user.messages
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    current_user.messages.create(message_params)
    redirect_to '/messages'
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:title, :body, :sender_id, :recipient_id)
  end

  def message
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

message/new view

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
     <%= hidden_field_tag :sender_id, current_user.id %>
     <%= f.text_field :title %>
     <%= f.text_field :body %>
     <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160517131719) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "surname"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "contacts", ["user_id"], name: "index_contacts_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "surname"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "contacts", "users"
end
```

Comment: Not an exact answer, but there's a great tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZjMQsVdc_w#t=2m30s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your form to this:

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :sender_id, value: current_user.id %> 
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :body %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @blastoff please up vote/accept the answer if it worked

Comment: i already tried to ticked up but it says i don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently the database is only receiving a user_id to the recipient_id
>   column which is wrong and should be to sender_id column.

In your `create` action, you have `current_user.messages.create(message_params)`. This creates a `message` record in the *DB* with the ***foreign key's***(i.e, `recipient_id` in your case) value with the `parent's(user) id`. This is the reason, the `recipient_id` gets the value of ***user's id***.

> Sender_id receives nothing.

This is because the `hidden_field` set for `sender_id` is not wrapped with the ***form builder*** instance. You need to change

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :sender_id, current_user.id %>
```

to

```
<%= f.hidden_field :sender_id, current_user.id %>
```

Comment: tks @Pavan that is interesting. So this is set in the model of User? but why doesn't it produce this for the sender_id as well then as both sender_id and recipient_id are set in User model?

Comment: @blastoff This is because `sender_id` is ***not*** the `foreign_key` for `messages`. It is the `foreign_key` for `sent_messages`.